# It is possible to declare string[] with a specific name?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, declaration

I'm studying the `string` type, and I stumbled across `char string[]`. Its confusing and I don't even know what it is. Its strange that i can't declare a `string` after I use it, because its using like a variable and it doesn't allow me to declare other strings. So how to add a name to that char array? Here is the code so I hope its understandable what I mean. Thanks.

```
#include "iostream"
#include "string.h"

using namespace std;


int main(){


    char string[] = "hello stackoverflow";
    string word("hello stackoverflow"); //cant declare "word" 
    //because i declare it above, and i want to know how to avoid that..

    cout<<word; 
    cout<<string;
}
```

the code I'm studying is this:

```
/*  Trim fat from windows*/
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#pragma comment(linker, "/subsystem:windows")
/*  Pre-processor directives*/

#include <windows.h>
#include "string.h"
/*  Windows Procedure Event Handler*/
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM       lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT paintStruct;
    /*  Device Context*/
    HDC hDC;
    /*  Text for display*/
    char string [] = "hi im a form"; //this is whats i don't understand what     //it is
    /*  Switch message, condition that is met will execute*/
    switch(message)
    {
        /*  Window is being created*/
        case WM_CREATE:
            return 0;
            break;
    /*  Window is closing*/
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage('0');
        return 0;
        break;
    /*  Window needs update*/
    case WM_PAINT:
        hDC = BeginPaint(hwnd,&paintStruct);
        /*  Set txt color to blue*/
        SetTextColor(hDC, COLORREF(0xffff1a));
        /*  Display text in middle of window*/
        TextOut(hDC,150,150,string,sizeof(string)-1); //and here why its //only able to declare it as "string" and not as a name
        EndPaint(hwnd, &paintStruct);
        return 0;
        break;
    default:
        break;

}
return (DefWindowProc(hwnd,message,wParam,lParam));
}
```

Comment: Simple: don't say "using namespace std;"`. That will force you to say `std::string`. But in general, don't give objects the same name as classes. Basically don't give more than one thing the same name.

Comment: Ah, what's in a name... many things have names in C++: types, variables, functions, ... One name can mean different things in different contexts.

Comment: char is a type, you string is a name for an array of type char.

Answer (score 1):

```
char c_str[] = "hello";
```

This declares a variable named `c_str` of type `char [6]` a.k.a `static array of 6 chars` initialized with `"hello"`;

```
std::string cpp_string("hello");
```

This declares a variable named `cpp_string` of type `std::string` initialized with `"hello"`. If you add `using namespace std;`, then you can use `string` instead of `std::string`.

All declarations of a variable must have the same type. You cannot define a variable multiple times.

You should not declare a variable with the same name as a type.